# MongoDB - Update an object from a nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, filter

```
{ _id: 1, first : "Maria",
    travel : [
    { country: "Canada", visits: 3, rating: 7 },
    { country: "Poland", visits: 1, rating: 8 },
    { country: "Thailand", visits: 2, rating: 9 } ] },

{ _id: 2, first : "Chen",
    travel : [
    { country: "Thailand", visits: 3, rating: 7 },
    { country: "Canada", visits: 2, rating: 9 },
    { country: "Costa Rica", visits: 4, rating: 8 } ] },

{ _id: 3, first : "Gladys",
    travel : [
    { country: "Canada", visits: 1, rating: 8 },
    { country: "Thailand", visits: 2, rating: 9 },
    { country: "Australia", visits: 3, rating: 10 } ]}
])
```

I need to update the visits Maria made to Canada to 5, so I have to use some sort of "double filter" (?) But I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got how to make that "double filter" : Array filters and $[identifier]
[Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#update-specific-elements-of-an-array-of-documents)

```
db.viajeros.updateOne(  { first: "Maria"},
                        { $set: {"travel.$[elem].visits": 5}},
                        { arrayFilters: [{"elem.country": "Canada"}]}   )
```